# What is Different in Birkhat Hamazon During Khol Hamoed?

Tags: chol-hamoed

What do we say differently on khol hamoed (specifically khol hamoed Pesakh, but an answer for Sukkot would be nice too) in birkhat hamazon aside from ya’ale v’yavo? For example, do we say Shir Hama’alot? Do we say “הרחמן הוא ינחילנו שכלו טוב”? Do we say “magdil” or “migdol”?

Comment: One should say Al Neharot Bavel before benching after a meal and on days when there’s no tachanun one should say Shir HaMaalot BeShuv Hashem instead. The minhag is to say Shir HaMaalot at Seudot mitzvah as well.  http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zimmun#Shir_HaMaalot

Comment: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed#Birkat_HaMazon

Comment: Who is "we"? Are you asking about any practice or that of a particular community? AFAIK according to everyone you only need to say the 4 blessings with the addition of Yaaleh veYavo.

Comment: Ashkenazi I guess, but I wouldn’t have thought there would be different customs on the matter.

Comment: Well unless you edit to specify I guess you'll just find out about any other customs in the answers

Comment: That’s better. That way anyone with the question in the future can know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mishna Berura OC 490:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.490.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) paskens not to say the special Harachaman on Chol Hamoed.

We also say Shir Hamaalos (various sources [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Zimmun#Shir_HaMaalot)) and Migdol as per מגן אברהם סימן קפט סק"א

I'll edit in the actual sources on the other two when I come back.

Comment: Yaaleh v’yavo??

Comment: @DonielF reread the question please